# NodeJS: Error: Cannot find module 'ytdl-core'

Tags: node.js, require

I was creating a discord music bot in NodeJS, with discord.js as well, but whenever I run it, I get this error: (the file is not named module.js)

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ytdl-core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module.__load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\discord bot\bot.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

At first, I thought it was because I needed to npm install the module like I did with discord.js, but instead I got the same error.

Comment: So `npm i ytdl-core` gave you the *exact same* error?

Comment: Yes. However i did npm install ytdl-core, but i don't think that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require but don't install [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core).

Please install it with command :

```
npm install ytdl-core
```

or install with `yarn`:

```
yarn add ytdl-core
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have already done `npm install ytdl-core` and still you got an error.

1. Please make sure `ytdl-core` is installed.
2. Log suggests that `bot.js` require `ytdl-core`. So, please make sure that you have

> var ytdlCore = require("ytdl-core");

May this help you. Or please add more code so I can distinguish error.